# Make some inputs inside functions instead of main

Tags: python, object-oriented

I'm very new to OOP, and I'm trying to do it correctly!
I have been doing a simple friendbook where you can add, remove and show the friends you have. However, I dont know if I should be satisfied or not with my code.

```
class Friendbook:

    listOfFriends = {}

    def __init__(self, name, lastname):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname

    def addFriend(self):
        self.listOfFriends[self.name] = self.lastname

    def showFriends(self):
        for firstname, lastname in self.listOfFriends.items():
            print(firstname, lastname)

    def removeFriend(self):
        removeName = input("Enter name to remove\n")
        del self.listOfFriends[removeName]


while True:

    print("1. Add Friend\n2. Showfriends\n3. RemoveFriend\n9. Quit\n")
    try:
        selectedOption = int(input())
        if selectedOption == 1:
            name = input("Enter firstname\n") #Can i move this to a function?
            lastname = input("Enter lastname\n") #Can i move this to a function?
            makeFriends = Friendbook(name, lastname)
            makeFriends.addFriend()
        elif selectedOption == 2:
            makeFriends.showFriends()
        elif selectedOption == 3:
            makeFriends.removeFriend()
        elif selectedOption == 9:
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid option")
    except:
        print("Only integers allowed")
```

I'm happy with it except for the code related to `selectedoption` 1, can I do something to put it inside the function so it looks nicer?
What do you think about my code in general, appreciate feedback!

Answer (score 5):

You are using classes wrong. With your class, you can never have two friend books, because each instance uses the classes mutable `listOfFriends`. (N.B.: A dictionary called `listOf...` is not very helpful).

Instead, have one `FriendBook` object, and let its methods take arguments:

```
class FriendBook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.friends = set()

    def add(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.friends.add((firstname, lastname))

    def remove(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.friends.remove((firstname, lastname))

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join("{} {}".format(*name) for name in self.friends)
```

A few notes:

1. The friends are a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) now (this assumes that no two friends share the same first and last name, already a better assumption than yours, which assumed that every friend had a unique last name). You could also make it a `list`, you would just have to change `self.friends.add` to `self.friends.append`.
2. The [magic function `__str__`](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) allows simply calling `print(fb)`, where `fb` is an instance of `FriendBook`, to print the full list of friends.
3. I made the names a bit easier. Note that Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using `PascalCase` for classes and `snake_case` everywhere else.

For your main question, yes you can put these in a function:

```
def ask_name():
    first_name = input("Enter firstname\n")
    last_name = input("Enter lastname\n")
    return first_name, last_name
```

I would also slightly rewrite your main function, like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fb = FriendBook()
    while True:
        print("1. Add Friend\n2. Show Friends\n3. Remove Friend\n9. Quit\n")
        try:
            option = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print("Only integers allowed")
            continue
        if option == 1:
            fb.add(*ask_name())
        elif option == 2:
            print(fb)
        elif option == 3:
            fb.remove(*ask_name())
        elif option == 9:
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid option")
```

Notes:

1. I wrapped it all in a [`if __name__ == "__main__"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard to allow importing this class from another script.
2. I use the defined function to ask for the names and use [tuple unpacking](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html) to pass it to the methods.
3. I limited the scope of the `try...except` clause and made it more specific. Your current `except` covered everything, even, for example, the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. [You should almost always avoid doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797508/4042267).

Answer (score 0):

For the current amount of information stored it is fine (especially @Graipher's answer). However, if you might want to add information to each friend in the future then I might be better to make a `Friend` class. It would work like this:

```
class Friend:
    def__init__(self, firstname, lastname, age = None, address = None):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.address = address
    def __str__(self):
        age = ", " + str(self.age) if self.age != None else ""
        address = ", " + str(self.address) if self.address != None else ""
        return("{}, {}{}{}".format(self.firstname, self.lastname, age, address)

class Friendbook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.friends = set()
    def __str__(self):
        out = ""
        for friend in self.friends:
            out += str(friend) + "\n"
        return(out)
    def add_friend(self, friend):
        self.friends.add(friend)
    def remove_friend(self, friend):
        self.friends.remove(friend)


def ask_name():
    yes_age = input("Do you know their age (y/n): ").lower()
    yes_address = input("Do you know their address (y/n): ").lower()
    firstname = input("First name: ")
    lastname = input("Last name: ")
    age = input("Age: ") if yes_age == "y" else None
    address = input("Address: ") if yes_address == "y" else None
    return(firstname, lastname, age, address)

if name == __main__:
    fb = Friendbook()
    while True:
        print("1. Add Friend\n2. Show Friends\n3. Remove Friend\n9. Quit\n")
        try:
            option = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print("Only integers allowed")
            continue
        if option == 1:
            fb.add_friend(Friend(*ask_name()))
        elif option == 2:
            print(fb)
        elif option == 3:
            fb.remove_friend(Friend(*ask_name())
        elif option == 9:
            break
        else:
            print("Not valid!")
```

This code can also have more stuff put into individual friends so there could be a way to put their email in or even a command to the friend class to send them a message. Although this is longer currently, it adds an extra layer of abstraction which would make it easier to add more functionality.